# Count() function in mysql

Tags: mysql, count

my count function counts the records of the first table twice then add to that same result rather than add the count() of the two table records. How can I work around this?

```
SELECT 
uln.user_id, count(uln.user_id)+count(uln.user_id) as user_pet_notif_count
FROM
user_legislation_notifications uln
join user_petition_notifications upn
on upn.user_id = uln.user_id
where
uln.user_id = '7' and uln.isRead = '0'
and upn.user_id = '7' and upn.isRead = '0'
```

The result of this is user_id --> 7 user_pet_notif_id --> 28 rather than user_id --> 7 user_pet_notif_id --> 9

Comment: You're counting after doing the `JOIN`, so it counts the number of rows in the result, not the number of rows in the original tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the counts without joining, otherwise you're counting the number of rows in the result of the join.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM user_legislation_notifications
        WHERE user_id = '7' and isRead = '0')
    +  (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM user_petition_notifications
        WHERE user_id = '7' and isRead = '0') AS user_pet_notif_count
```

Comment: nice solution.. thanks!.. only question, is this also optimized because of subqueries or not?

Comment: Each subquery will be optimized using indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In `count(uln.user_id)+count(uln.user_id)` you are adding uln.user_id twice. Isn't one should be `upn.user_id`.

Comment: It doesn't matter. When you put an argument inside `count()`, it counts the number of non-null values of this column. But both of these are not null because of the `WHERE` condition, and they're the same because of the `ON` condition.

Comment: Post table here also please.